# Can we add Models in Layout.cshtml?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql, models

i have layout of 4 pages and at header i need to access name of logged in admin. how to access that database model in admin in starting of layout i have added

```
    @model ProjectName.Models.Admin
```

and while accessing name from admin i am writing

```
    @Model.Name
```

it gives error how to do it in proper way to access that attribute in Layout and it cant be partial view it should be layout so kindly help

Comment: Either use `@Html.Action()` in the layout to call a server method that returns a partial view, or use a base view model containing the properties you need and declare the base view model in the layout and in the view, use view models which derive from that base view model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Stephen Muecke stated in his comment on your question, there are more ways how you can do that. I would recommend you to keep your Layout view without model. Otherwise as @Stephen Muecke mentions, you would have to make types of models for each view that uses that layout of either the same or derived type, which would add unnecessary complexity to your code.

So the other way is to call `HtmlHelper.Action(...)` or `HtmlHelper.RenderAction()` in your layout view at the place when you'd like to render user's name. Example:

Layout page:

```
...
<div class="admin-name">
    @{ Html.RenderAction("AdminName", "Partial"); }
</div>
...
```

Add a controller:

```
public class PartialController : Controller {
    [ChildActionOnly] // action cannot be requested directly via URL
    public ActionResult AdminName() {
        string adminName = ...; // assign value to adminName variable
        return Content(adminName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need logged in user details in so many pages in application, so better to **store logged in user details in Session** and you can retrieve session value in any view/partial view.

**Other Solution:**

Make your header partial view and call from Layout

```
Html.RenderAction("actionName", "controllerName")
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an action method in your controller which returns partial view

Controller Action Method

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Header()
{
    HeaderModel HM = new HeaderModel()
    // Your user information in HeaderModel
    return PartialView("Header", HM)
}
```

_layout.cshtml

```
<body>
    <div>
        @{Html.RenderAction("Header", "ControllerName");}
    </div>
</body>
```

I hope this will resolve your problem.